# How to generate R.java file for integrating google maps

Tags: android

I am making an application to integrate google maps on an app. i have done all the stuff and even the app shows no error. bt while running it closes. "FORCE CLOSE". i checked my logcat it says r.java file not generated. please tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

r.java file is not created manually. The only thing we can try in this scenario is create new workspace and integrate the map sdk following the google api docs.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Build your project r.java file will generate there . Integrate Map SDK and Check your given permissions in android manifest.